# Error with animations module when upgrading to Angular4

Tags: angular, animation, systemjs

I am having an issue at the moment where when I include the 'BrowserAnimationsModule' module in my application I get the following errors:

```
(index):26 Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
        at __extends (http://degould-login.dev/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:15:68)
        at eval (http://degould-login.dev/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:328:5)
        at Object.eval (http://degould-login.dev/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:337:2)
        at Object.eval (http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js:36:20)
        at eval (http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js:82:4)
        at eval (http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js:83:3)
        at eval (<anonymous>)
    Evaluating http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://degould-login.dev/app/main.js
    Error loading http://degould-login.dev/app/main.js
        at __extends (http://degould-login.dev/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:15:68)
        at eval (http://degould-login.dev/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:328:5)
        at Object.eval (http://degould-login.dev/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:337:2)
        at Object.eval (http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js:36:20)
        at eval (http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js:82:4)
        at eval (http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js:83:3)
        at eval (<anonymous>)
    Evaluating http://degould-login.dev/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://degould-login.dev/app/main.js
    Error loading http://degould-login.dev/app/main.js
(anonymous) @ (index):26
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:365
Zone.run @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:125
(anonymous) @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:760
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:398
Zone.runTask @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:165
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:593
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:464
```

I have been trying to figure this out but I can't for the life of me see what is going wrong here.

I added these three lines to my SystemJS config file under the'map' property:

```
 '@angular/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
```

And I have included the module in my NgModule object:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";


//Instantiate the Angular Object
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

The error is thrown before the page even get's an opportunity to load.

Can anyone provide any insight as to what is happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reinstall / restart the app?

Comment: Yes I have tried reinstalling the NPM packages and restarting the app. Doesn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: having the same issue too, my npm packages are all updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and followed this process and it worked for me:

1. Create a new project using Angular CLI as

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ng new PROJECT-NAME
   cd PROJECT-NAME
   ng serve
   ```
2. Borrow "dependencies" of package.json from the project created by Angular CLI and replace your project's package.json with that
3. Install required npm packages using this command

   ```
   npm install --save
   ```

Comment: error comes back even after importing `BrowserAnimationsModule`